# isinstance(object, type) is giving me an error - Also, flattening a nested list

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner programmer, and I attempted to solve one of the prolog questions which was to flatten a nested list. My attempt:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3], 4, 5]

def flatten(list):
    new = []
    for i in list:
        new.append(','.join(int(i)) for i in list)
    for ele in list:
        if isinstance(ele, list):
            flatten(ele)
            return new
        else:
            pass
        return new

flatten(a)
```

I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types.
```

I thought I implemented it correctly since I passed on ele (the object) and list (type)? It worked in the interpreter, but not here.

Also any advice for the code in terms of trying to flatten a nested list?

Comment: using list as variable name is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

By doing `def flatten(list)`, you used `list` as the name of your function parameter, which blocks access to the builtin type named `list`.  Use a different name for your variable.

As for how to flatten nested lists, googling that question will give you dozens if not hundreds of answers.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I tried to not look at any other answer while trying to create my own. When I tried to run the program, I just had a list of object instances rather than a flattened list of integers. But I will definitely look it up, I just hoped I would get a reason why my code might have not worked (so I can learn what type of thinking is right/how my thinking was wrong).

Comment: @Naz: You kind of asked two questions in one.  If you fixed the error I mentioned and you still have questions about why your code is doing what it does, you could ask a separate question.  However, it would be a good idea to phrase such a question as "why does doing X result in Y", with examples of your input and output data, and not "how do I flatten a nested list", because if you ask how to flatten a nested list, people are going to close your question as a duplicate of existing ones about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `list` as variable in your `flatten(list)` function.

Please avoid to use variable name of data type. Please change it to `flatten(my_list)` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

there are some flaw in your code:

```
1 never use list as variable name
2 new.append(','.join(int(i)) for i in list)  
   `join` wont take int type, will raise TypeError
    it should be new.append(','.join(str(i)))
3 you are using `return` once it returned , it come out of the function
```